# How to toggle class angular2 using *ngIf

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello I need toggle class using angular2 `*ngIf` statement

`<i *ngIf="visible" [(ngClass)]="{{arrow}}"></i>` << this line of code not work correctly

---

here is my `ts` code

```
private visible = true;
private i = 0;
private arrow = 'ic-v';
private showList(){
    if(this.i == 0){
        this.i = 1;
        this.visible = false;
        this.arrow = 'ic-v-up';
    }
    else
    {
        this.i = 0;
        this.visible = true;
        this.arrow = 'ic-v';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ngClass is directive, use it as [ngClass] as attribute binding directive.

```
[ngClass]="arrow"
```

OR More better

```
[ngClass]="{ 'ic-v': visible, 'ic-v-up': !visible }"
```

[**Demo Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/jk7DHUtoI6UFfCSbmW0N?p=preview)

Comment: zone.js:388Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 41 in [{ 'ic-v': visible, 'ic-v-up': !visible }=$event] in TransactionsComponent@40:39 ("                <div>market</div>

Comment: @ValDo have you import `BrowserModule` in your `AppModule`?

Comment: @ValDo then it should work, could you create plunkr/fiddle?

Comment: @ValDo. Your Plunkr still has your old syntax with `[(ngClass)]`...  Use the correction provided by Pankaj.

Comment: @ValDo though I added plunker in my answer.. please check you had again mistaken `[(ngClass)]` instead of `[ngClass]`